# In Revit how to do interference detecting programmatically?

Tags: revit

More precisely, how can I determine if a Solid is intersecting another element?
I looked over the Revit API and could not find any information on this.

Answer (score 1):

have a look into the ray projection API, you can shoot a ray in a certain direction and it will return all the elements it hits and their locations etc.

FindReferencesByDirection method I believe is the method that does that.

Answer (score 1):

In Revit 2012, use the ElementIntersectsSolidFilter while filtering elements.  You supply the input Solid which could come from another element or from geometry you generate programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

if you looking for intersected elements,I'll use BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter ,it's quick filter with minor performance impact

first,get the geometry boundingbox

```
GeometryElement geoElem = wall.get_Geometry(_geoOpt) as GeometryElement;
BoundingBoxXYZ boundXYZ = geoElem.GetBoundingBox();
```

then,create the outline and passed to BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter

```
if (boundXYZ != null)
{
  outline = new Outline(boundXYZ.Min, boundXYZ.Max);
  boundingFilter = new BoundingBoxIntersectsFilter(outline);

  var filterElems = new FilteredElementCollector(elem.Document).WherePasses(boundingFilter).ToElementIds();
  foreach (var item in filterElems)
  {
     //retrieve intersected elements
  }
}
```